# inspiron 7720 woofer is dead Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: 18.04

Bought the laptop with Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS installed on it.
I have not ever had anything other than Windows so I know not one thing about all this.

The woofer does not work and i cant seem to get it to work.
I have tried every thing i can find but still no luck.
any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the exact answer you're looking for but will open up some options.
Install pavucontrol:

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

Then,

- Hit your "Windows" key
- Type "pavu" and click the "PulseAudio Volume Control" button that will come up.

From there, you'll have a much better view of what the system "sees" in your hardware configuration.  It may even offer the solution to your problem - play around with it.

EDIT:
You'll be specifically interested in the "Playback", "Output Devices", and "Configuration" tabs.